# MVC controller global variable from query string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Is it possible to work with a global variable that need to receive the data from a query string in MVC controller?

```
public string Layout = Request.QueryString["Layout"];
```

At the moment I am working with a Session variable - but i want to use a global variable so it will be available all over my controller functions.
Thanks

Comment: yes you can do it. But what i suggest you is. Declare a variable in controller and assign it in controller constructor.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a certain page that i wish to redirect from with a parameter in the query string, this parameter should be received by the Controller and should be available through out the entire controller and functions.

Comment: You may use TempData but don't forget to use the Keep() method to keep  the data upon navigating from one controller to other.

Answer (score 0):

If you want global variable that will be global for all requests in your App you can use [`HttpContext.Application`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.httpcontext.application(v=vs.110).aspx).

You can use it like this in any `Controller` method:

```
// set variable
HttpContext.Application["MyGlobalVar"] = 777; 
//get your variable
var myGlobalVar = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Application["MyGlobalVar"])
```

Note that it stored like `object` so you should convert your variable when you get it.